# How to define a user-defined event to be measured by PAPI?

Tags: assembly, profiling, papi

Most of today's processors are equipped with hardware performance counters. Such counters can be used to count micro-architecture events in order to analyse the target program to improve its performance. Generally, profiling and analysing are the main goals of these counters.

Based on research papers presented in literatures, these counters lack accuracy. For example, if we want to count the number of retired instructions in a given code, the value may be change from run to another, perturbation problem.
Several guidelines have been discussed to increase accuracy in measurements. Monitoring multiple events can provide better understand about the program being executed, and therefore increasing measurements accuracy.

Authors of [User-defined events for hardware performance monitoring](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1877050911002870/1-s2.0-S1877050911002870-main.pdf?_tid=0602c97e-6e5e-4edd-bac0-714999b1bf1f&acdnat=1551786780_6e9f9365423f7369a9eb3c3b51e8cd5d) have been proposed a new method to enable users to define their own events to be used by PAPI ([Performance API](http://icl.utk.edu/papi/)) which is an infrastructure widely used to access the hardware performacne counters in easy way. Unfortunately, the paper does not explain in detail how we define user-defined events and use them in our program.

For example (based on PAPI), I seek to define a new event that involves *n* native/preset events like (PAPI_TOT_INS, PAPI_BR_TKN and PAPI_STR_INS), and then use it as a single event in my code.

---

edited:

Based on the mentioned paper, I set the environment variable PAPI USER_EVENTS FILE to indicate to the file that contains user-defined events and this file will initiate and parse by calling PAPI_library_init function. 
The event_file is very simple (just for testing):

```
#define a 5

tot_ins, PAPI_TOT_CYC|a|*
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <papi.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

long_long val[10000]; 

 int EventSet = PAPI_NULL;
 long_long values[1];

PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);
PAPI_create_eventset(&EventSet);

//tot_ins is the name of the event defined in event-file
int counter_code;
PAPI_event_name_to_code("tot_ins",& counter_code);
printf("code =%x\n",counter_code);

PAPI_add_event(EventSet,counter_code);

int k;
int index=0;

for (k=0; k<5; k++)
{  

       PAPI_start(EventSet);

int i;

for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
int x;
int y;
int z;

x=i+2;
y=x+i/15;
z=x/y;

}

       PAPI_read(EventSet, values) ;
       //printf("test number  %d        %lld \n",k,values[0]);
       printf("%lld\n",values[0]);
       PAPI_stop(EventSet, values) ;

printf("\n---------------------------------- \n");
 }// end k 

}
```

**However, the output is seem to be strange for both counting and counter_code**

I defined a simple event in a text file (in Linux Ubuntu OS) and set environment variable to indicate to this file.  But in the code, both

```
PAPI_event_name_to_code("tot_ins",& counter_code); //(retvalue=-7)
```

and

```
PAPI_add_event(EventSet,counter_code); //(retvalue=-10)
```

return a value not equal to PAPI_OK.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The paper gives an example of two user defined events. It boils down to writing them in a file (its path either set in an envar or passed to the PAPI functions). The format is quite simple: `event_name,event_formula` where `event_formula` is a Reverse Polish Notation for an expression involving other events and constants. One of the examples given is `PAPI_BR_INS|BR_lat|*|PAPI_BR_MSP|BR_miss_lat|*|+|PAPI_TOT_INS|/` which is `(PAPI_BR_INS * BR_lat + PAPI_BR_MSP * BR_miss_lat) / PAPI_TOT_INS`

Comment: @MargaretBloom, thank you very much, however I have tested many programs but I always got result=0.  I edited the question and added additional info. Thanx.

Comment: How are you passing the name of the file with the custom events to PAPI?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, as I understood from the mentioned paper, we should set the PAPI USER_EVENTS FILE environment variable to indicate to the file that contains user-defined events. After that, by calling PAPI_library_init function, PAPI (maybe) will recognize our events that defined in the file. For this reason, PAPI_set_opt wasn't used and I did not passed any file to PAPI. 
I may have misunderstood and implemented the instructions in the article in wrong way.

Comment: PAPI_USER_EVENTS should be fine, maybe double check it? Your code works in my machine but I had to fix it, it doesn't compile as given.

Comment: The code runs fine, however the result seems to be incorrect. Meaning that, either PAPI can't recognize event_file or the code itself is not correct.

Comment: I got a non-zero counter code and non-zero metrics, furthermore the metrics change when the file is changed (e.g. scaled). I haven't checked the validity of the metrics returned by `PAPI_TOT_CYC`, I assumed they are correct. By changing the `a` constant you can check if the file is correctly parsed.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, thank you very much for your help. Please can you show me your code that you tested? I have tested many times and changed the content of the  event_file but I always got a zero result :(

Comment: I tested your code, I just fixed a few warnings (you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/SPAa14R9)). Did you do a `export PAPI_USER_EVENTS_FILE=...` before launching the program?

Comment: I got non-zero but wrong results, code=547ebf587 and the measurements seem strange and not correct. This often happens due to configure the hardware counter in wrong way. **Did you do a export PAPI_USER_EVENTS_FILE=...**  absolutely yes

Comment: @MargaretBloom, what type the file you defined is? I defined events in a text file. I have edited the question and added some extra info. BTW, all the results I have got are not true. and both PAPI functions for convert event's name and adding event to Eventset were return error.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is lost and landing here:

I had the same issue and tried setting the environment variable `PAPI_USER_EVENTS_FILE` but it did not work in the beginning. Then I figured out that I was setting the PMU name wrong and how to get the correct PMU names. Minimal working example on my IvyBridge CPU which defines an alias for `PAPI_DP_OPS`:

```
# ivybridge
CPU,ivb
EVENT,USER_DP_OPS,NOT_DERIVED,PAPI_DP_OPS,NOTE,'FLOPS'
```

The mistake was that I used the content of the pmu_name file instead of the pmu name used by PAPI:

```
cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name
ivybridge
```

You can query the available PMU names with `papi_component_avail`, as given in the man-page `man PAPI_derived_event_files`. The file `papi_events.csv` (see below) contains the preset events and all the PMU names used by PAPI. The man-page also describes the syntax of the user events file. `papi_avail` will show the added user event if it worked.

However, I think it is **buggy**: e.g. the alias shows completely different numbers for the dp ops. The documentation about this feature should be improved in my opinion and the man-page for the user-defined derived event file does not contain how to specify the file.

---

`PAPI_set_opt`, as described as an alternative in the referenced paper, is currently (6.0.0.1) not supported as a way to specify the user-defined eventfile and will return an error number (error string 'null'): (from papi_preset.c)

> - There are three possible sources of input for preset event definitions.  The code will first look for the environment variable "PAPI_CSV_EVENT_FILE".  If found its value will be used as the pathname of where to get the preset information.  If not found, the code will look for a built in table containing preset events.  If the built in table was not created during the build of PAPI then the code will build a pathname of the form "PAPI_DATADIR/PAPI_EVENT_FILE".  Each of these are build variables, the PAPI_DATADIR variable can be given a value during the configure of PAPI at build time, and the PAPI_EVENT_FILE variable has a hard coded value of "papi_events.csv".

> - There is only one way to define user events.  The code will look for an environment variable "PAPI_USER_EVENTS_FILE".  If found its value will be used as the pathname of a file which contains user event definitions.  The events defined in this file will be added to the ones known by PAPI when the call to PAPI_library_init is done.

> - TODO:
> - Look into restoring the ability to specify a user defined event file with a call to PAPI_set_opt(PAPI_USER_EVENTS_FILE).
> - This needs to figure out how to pass a pmu name (could use default pmu from component 0) to this function.
> - Currently code elsewhere in PAPI limits the events which preset and user events can depend on to those events which are known to component 0.  This possibly could be relaxed to allow events from different components.  But since all the events used by any derived event must be added to the same eventset, it will always be a requirement that all events used by a given derived event must be from the same component.